# buddypress not assign gravatar in user's profile

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, gravatar

i use buddypress and when a user get the registration has assigned a defaut gravatar for each one.

It's not possible to assign the gravatar, that is associated to email address at site gravatar.com ?

i don't understand

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Discussion and at the bottom of that page check Gravatar Logo as Default Avatar